# Project Euler problem 2 in Haskell

Tags: beginner, programming-challenge, haskell, fibonacci-sequence

I have just started Haskell, and I want to check if my code is following the spirit of the language.

> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

```
fibonacci :: [Int]
fibonacci = 1 : 1 : (next 1 1)
    where
    next x y = sxy : (next y sxy)
        where
        sxy = x + y

main = do
    putStrLn $ show $ sum $ filter odd $ takeWhile (< 4000000) fibonacci
```

Comment: Relevant: https://wiki.haskell.org/The_Fibonacci_sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a few things to point out.

There is a prelude function `print` that is defined `print = putStrLn . show`.

Additionally, using "do-notation" in this case is unnecessary as you aren't sequencing multiple IO actions.

`main` can be rewritten in a more point-free style using the function composition operator:

```
main = print . sum . filter odd . takeWhile (< 4000000) $ fibonacci
```

I might rewrite `fibonacci` like this (removes nested `where` clauses):

```
fibonacci :: [Int]
fibonacci = next 1 1
  where next x y = x : next y (x + y)
```

And [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/The_Fibonacci_sequence) are a bunch of other ways to define `fibonacci`. One interesting way that is possible because of Haskell's laziness:

```
fibonacci = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibonacci (tail fibonacci)
```